# How to compute split_gain in lightgbm of python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I wonder how lightgbm compute split_gain.
I saw `split_gain = sum_grad / sum_hess` at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1283).

but, I saw that is not true.
Source is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
from lightgbm.plotting import *

d = pd.DataFrame({"x1":[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2],"y":[4, 1, 0, 1, 4]})
```

```
def custom_asymmetric_train(y_true, y_pred):
    residual = (y_true - y_pred).astype("float")
    grad = np.where(residual<0, -2*10.0*residual, -2*residual)
    hess = np.where(residual<0, 2*10.0, 2)
    print(grad, hess, sum(grad), sum(hess))
    return grad, hess
```

```
l2 = LGBMRegressor(min_child_samples=1, min_child_weight=0, n_estimators=5, max_depth=1, learning_rate=1, min_gain_to_split=0, objective=custom_asymmetric_train)

l2.fit(d[["x1"]], d[["y"]].values.ravel())
```

```
create_tree_digraph(booster=l2, show_info=['split_gain', 'internal_value', 'internal_count', 'leaf_count'], tree_index=0)
```

and output is

```
[-8. -2. -0. -2. -8.] [2. 2. 2. 2. 2.] -20.0 10.0
[-4.66666667 13.33333333 33.33333333 30.         -3.        ] [ 2. 20. 20. 20.  2.] 68.99999999999999 64.0
[-5.45454544  5.4545456   4.60317521  1.26984188 -5.87301581] [ 2. 20. 20. 20.  2.] 1.4305114603985203e-06 64.0
[-5.67374426  3.26255743  2.41118704  5.45454549 -5.45454545] [ 2. 20. 20. 20.  2.] 2.3841856311435095e-07 64.0
[-5.45454547  5.45454533  1.26300278  4.30636123 -5.56936388] [ 2. 20. 20. 20.  2.] -1.509903313490213e-14 64.0
```

[image]

I have tried another conditions, but I didn't know how lgbm comput split gain.

let me know please.

Comment: Did you figure out the solution? It seems weird that the split gain is always sum(grad)/sum(hessian), I suppose for classification and regression, the way to calculate split gain may be different, and based on different purity measure, like gini or entropy, the split gain might be different, too